# Customize display value of ng-multiselect dropdown value

Tags: multi-select, angular8

I have a ng-multiselect dropdown. When I select all the values Instead of displaying all the values from the dropdown It should just display "All" in the dropdown.

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
            [placeholder]="dropdowns.label"
            [data]="dropdowns.optionsList"
            [(ngModel)]="dropdowns.value"
            [settings]="dropdownSettings"
            (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
            (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
          >

this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: 'item_id',
      textField: 'item_text',
      selectAllText: 'All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      itemsShowLimit: 3,
      allowSearchFilter: false
    };
```

When selected all the dropdowns it should display 'All' in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

you can try by changing the value of **dropdowns.value** with "ALL" when you select all options.
and you can do this in this event `(onSelectAll)`.

In .ts file:

```
onSelectAll(event){dropdowns.value="ALL"}
```

Comment: I have made few changes in ng-multiselectdropdown.js template and style but when I build in production mode I wont get the changes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have done some changes in `node_module` and you are not able to get changes in build. It's common in angular. Angular will not get your custom changes in the production build.

If you your custom changes works fine then use this command to make a build. With the help of this command you will get your changes in build.

```
ng build --aot=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot for implementing the same but couldn't find any solution as it is already built library.

I've found an alternative for it. Set the itemShowLimit to 0, this means there won't be any item to display. In that case, add a span right next to the multiselect dropdown and adjust the position accordingly. Worked for me :)

Sample code:
In .ts file:

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
  singleSelection: false,
  idField: 'item_id',
  textField: 'item_text',
  selectAllText: 'All',
  unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
  itemsShowLimit: 0,
  allowSearchFilter: false
};
```

In HTML File:

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
        [placeholder]="dropdowns.label"
        [data]="dropdowns.optionsList"
        [(ngModel)]="dropdowns.value"
        [settings]="dropdownSettings"
        (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
        (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
      ><span>All</span>
```

I have customized display as I wanted to show the number of items selected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsmRN.png